# How we can measure cpu time for a method using PerformanceCounter?

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter, measurement

I want to measure cpu time for a method Not using StopWatch or Process but using the .NET profiler PerformanceCounter.

I see that their is only method to calculate how much cpu is used by a process

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", ProcessName);
CounterSample cs1 = cpuCounter.NextSample();
```

But i'm looking for all the time spent in the process using this API.

Comment: Is this method you are measuring inside your code or are you trying to measure a 3rd party program? Also, from your comments to Patrik's answer, this sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem, you think using a Performance Counter is the solution, so you are asking about how to use a Performance Counter. Instead of doing that **edit your question to ask about your actual problem you are trying to solve**, you can mention that you think a Performance Counter is the way to solve it but you might be given a better solution

Comment: I already used StopWatch And Process as mentioned on the question and it's not accurate. I'm trying to check if someone already use The PerformanceCounter to measure time of method(Call External or Interal Code within the method).
If i run the method few times with Process or StopWatch to measure time it give me severals values With >0 Interval between Them.
So i'm looking to found the best method where the interval ==> 0

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it is not possible. The `PerformanceCounter` is designed to read the systems process information. The system has no information about what you actually doing within your process.

In a single-threaded application you can use the `PerformanceCounter` and select the value from begin to end of the method-execution (just call `NextSample` once before the method is called and gather the result calling it afterwards).

As a non-programmatic approach you can use Visual Studios Performance Profiling tool to gather more information about how much time your application spent on which method. It gives you a very in-depth information concerning the cpu-consumption of your application. A quick introduction is given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182372.aspx).

Comment: So If I can run this method into a process so i can count the cpu time of this process ? but NextSample give the number of %cpu used not the time right ?

Comment: Each sample has its amount of time. The value which `NextSample` returns describes the time-period elapsed since the last call. So invoke it once per second and you get the percentage cpu used in that second -> 70% for 1 second is 0.7 seconds in CPU-time. The approach isn't 100% accurate but pretty close which mostly suffices. A more accurate way would be to measure the elapsed time between to calls (using `Stopwatch`) and calculate the CPU-time then.

Comment: Yes Nextsample Return just The %cpu used not the time taken by the process during cpu (like Process.TotalProcess) But The StopWatch will calculate just facial time including other background process when they are in Cpu (Schedular stuff). And it's not accurate too.
So The best i think is to calculate our timer like the timer Used but StopWatch But i don't know how to do it. If u have any idea on how creating this Timer, it will very helpfull for me ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your timer. But using Stopwatch and PerformanceCounter together yields the percantage of cpu usage on a given period of time, which is, multiplicated, the cpu time.

Comment: I already used StopWatch And Process as mentioned on the question and it's not accurate. I'm trying to check if someone already use The PerformanceCounter to measure time of method(Call External or Interal Code within the method). If i run the method few times with Process or StopWatch to measure time it give me severals values With >0 Interval between Them. So i'm looking to found the best method where the interval ==> 0

Comment: Think of the XY-Problem. Is there maybe a better approach to the problem? What you want to achieve in perfect accuracy  is not possible.